# Алгоритм определения коллизии цилиндра и сложного тела

Tags: алгоритм, 3d

Дано:

1) Сложное тело (меш ландшафта), состоящее из треугольных полигонов

2) Простое тело (к примеру цилиндр). Для него известна точка центра и все его измерения.

Нужен алгоритм определения наличия пересечения этих двух тел. При этом, сложное тело много больше простого (по размерам и количеству вершин).

Основная задача - как можно быстрее ответить, есть ли пересечение между этими телами. Допускается предобработка сложного тела.

Какие вообще есть подходы для решения подобной задачи?

---

Так же скажу сразу, что нужен именно алгоритм, а не какой-то физический движок, который все это сам определит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разбить поиск на этапы. Первый это грубое отсечение, по крайним координатам тел. Если коллизия не найдена, значит тела не пересекаются. Если найдена, тогда преступаем к детальному отсечению по полигонам попавшим в эту область.

Можете почитать более детально про алгоритмы **Sweep And Prune** и **V-Clip**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите быстро - надо математически:

По сути, необходимо проверить на пересечение каждого примитива из которого состоит сложное тело с цилиндром.

Допустим известно уравнение поверхности какой-то части сложного тела, тогда наличие решения системы из двух уравнений, в котором первое - уравнение этой поверхности, а второе - параметрическое(либо ещё какое-то) уравнение цилиндра, даст ответ пересекаются ли они (тоесть имеют ли общие точки).

Если с хотя бы одной частью есть пересечение алгоритм останавливается, иначе нету пересечений.